set env variables from a cron job
I am trying to run a script in a cron job on reboot to set an env variable to be used later (by PM2)
I have tried to source the script when running in crontab with
. /home/myuser/scripts/startup.sh

I have tried to add the PATH to the script but again no luck.
My script so far is
#!/bin/bash
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
export ENV_TYPE = 'dev'

but when I check
echo $ENV_TYPE

it returns empty.
The entry in /ect/crontab is the following:
@reboot         myuser        /home/myuser/scripts/startup.sh >> /home/myuser/scripts/logs/startup.log 2>&1
Nothing is logged to the startup.log

Setting and exporting variables in a script is only meaningful for its child processes. Do such a thing in cron is just useless.

@user68186 no I would like to do the opposite. Or to set somehow an env variable by default before the PM2 service start

Variables set and exported in a script are only available to child processes started in that script and are not available to subsequent processes like PM2.
To make ENV_TYPE persistent you can set the variable in a global profile file /etc/environment. You can edit this file with sudo and add a line like this to the end of it:
ENV_TYPE=dev

Please, note that the you have put spaces around = in your sample script; spaces are not allowed around = and any other literal spaces to the right of it should be quoted.
As a better way, you can pass the environment variable explicitly when starting PM2 (the command below is just an example):
ENV_TYPE=dev /path/to/pm2 any parameters

